# Fail using PyDev test runner

Tags: python, unit-testing, pydev

I have created a default unit test module in PyDev. The module is as follows:

```
import unittest
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass


    def tearDown(self):
        pass


    def testName(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2) #here I expect to see failure message


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

I then use "Run as -> Python unit-test" option to perform the unit tests. All I see  in the output console is the following two lines:

> Finding files... done.
>
> Importing test modules ...

And then nothing. Eclipse behaves as if the tests are being executed, but nothing really happens. I can click the "stop" button in order to terminate the test, but if I don't nothing happens.

*NOTE*  that when searching the Net, I figured out that the output above should include file and module names (see [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1478005&group_id=85796&atid=577329) for example)

If I use the "Run as -> python run" option, the tests are performed as expected. I am sure that I miss something about using PyDev test runner, but can't find out what.

Changing the test* function names from `testName` to `test_name` didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the problem.

It turns out that several parts of inititalization code of my modules rely on parsing `sys.argv[0]`. This worked fine when using "Run As -> Python Run" as `sys.argv[0]` contained the expected path to the executed program. When using "Run As -> Python unit tests", the running program is "runfiles.py" in PyDev plugin directory. This unexpected change caused an infinite loop, which I interpretered as "nothing happens". I will treat this behaviour as a design fault and revise the problematic parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think (operating from memory) that your should prefix the test name with test_ (underscore required).